# Invoking WCF no parameter method from Biztalk orchestration

Tags: xml, wcf, biztalk

I'm new at Biztalk, I've been making some tutorials, now I have an issue I don`t' find the solution but think is kind of easy

I have a WCF Service method with no parameters that returns an XML file.
I want to call this method from biztalk orchestration, I have used the "Add ->Generated Item –> Consume WCF Service" wizard to generate the schemas and to be able to create a request, response port.

Now I just have to send a request to this service, an XML specifying the method I want to call. But I dont want to drop an XML file whits this message in a folder, read from there, and then call service.

It doesnt have parameters, so I want to generate the message in the orchestration and automatically call the service with it. How can I contruct the message from "nothing" just the schema?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a request message in your Orchestration in a Message Assignment shape.
Create a message type matching the request message - e.g msgRequest. In the Construct Shape, set the outgoing message to msgRequest. Go to the schema for the request and Generate an instance of that schema. Use the load xml method to assign the xDoc variable to the msgRequest message.

the expression would be something like:

`xDoc = new System.XmlDocument(); 
xDoc.LoadXml("<GeneratedRequest/>"); 
Message_1.body = xDoc;`

Comment: and the expression inside, something like that? : Message_1.parameters = null;

Comment: Sorry Juan - i'm having a lot of difficulty trying to post my full answer!! keep getting errors...

Comment: right - fire alram just went off so had to evacuate! Anyways, the xml you generate from the schema will contain everything you need for the request. If message_1 is a multipart message, just set the body part to be the xDoc (xml value). Send Message_1 as the request and you should be good!

Comment: sorry - to address you question properly, the expression would be something like:
xDoc = new System.XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml("<GeneratedRequest/>");
Message_1.<Body> = xDoc;
Message_1.body = xDoc

Comment: to generate xml from the schema, open the XSD that was generated when you performed your "Add Generated Items...".
It will contain the Request and Response Schemas.
Click on the Schema node in the Tree and ensure that the "Root Reference" property is set to the Request that you want to generate.
Right click on the Xsd in the Solution explorer and select "generate instance". Copy this - and make sure you clear the "Root Reference" property (by setting it back to default)!

Comment: Hi Juan, has your problem been solved? If not, do you need any more help?

Comment: At the end I took another workaround (published the orchrestation as a  WCF Service) anyway your answer was helpful, I will mark it as an answer but I think would be helpful for everybody putting all the comments in the answer, reformating it

Comment: Hi Juan, that's a good idea - i'll update the answer. Glad you found a solution.